# Pattern to handle both command line arguments and/or api method parameters

Tags: python, api, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm trying to setup a code that can be run via the command-line with command-line arguments, or can be called from a python script or interactive session --- with passed parameters.  What is a good pattern/methodology to do this?

The basic idea I'm using right now is:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


class Sets:
    def __init__(self):
        self.verbose = False
        self.par = 1
        self.args = ['run', 'test']

    def _update(self, parsed):
        for key in vars(parsed).keys():
            setattr(self, key, getattr(parsed, key))
            print("\t", getattr(self, key))


def main(**kwargs):
    sets = _parseArgs()
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        setattr(sets, key, kwargs[key])

    print("verbose = ", sets.verbose)
    print("par = ", sets.par)
    print("args = ", sets.args)

    return


def _parseArgs():
    sets = Sets()
    pars = ArgumentParser()
    pars.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true', default=sets.verbose)
    pars.add_argument('--par', nargs=1, type=int, default=sets.par)
    pars.add_argument('--args', nargs='+', type=str, default=sets.args)
    sets._update(pars.parse_args())
    return sets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But it seems a little convoluted...

Comment: How were you intending to use this in a session or script?

Comment: @hpaulj if I understand the terminology correctly: both --- both interactive/as-imported-functions and as an executable script.

Answer (score 1):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def main(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pars = ArgumentParser()
    pars.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
    pars.add_argument('--par', nargs=1, type=int, default=1)
    pars.add_argument('--args', nargs='+', type=str, default=['run', 'test'])

    main(**vars(pars.parse_args()))
```

Output:

```
{'par': 1, 'args': ['run', 'test'], 'verbose': False}
```

Or:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def main(args):
    print(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pars = ArgumentParser()
    pars.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
    pars.add_argument('--par', nargs=1, type=int, default=1)
    pars.add_argument('--args', nargs='+', type=str, default=['run', 'test'])

    main(pars.parse_args())
```

Which outputs:

```
Namespace(args=['run', 'test'], par=1, verbose=False)
```

... but you can access it more easily, i.e. `args.args`, `args.par`, `args.verbose`.

Comment: You don't need `dict` here: `dict(vars(...))`.  `vars()` returns a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks!  This is definitely a big step cleaner --- the `Sets` object should have been more obviously superfluous...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Sets` class appears to be ok, though I haven't tested it.  But it is, I think, more convoluted than you need.  Putting the `main` call in the the `if __name__` block is right.  Sometimes the parser is defined there as well, but that's not essential.

As long as the argument names are not unusual, you can access the values as attributes.

```
 args = parser.parse_args()
 print("verbose = ", args.verbose)
 print("par = ", args.par)
 print("args = ", args.args)
```

You could construct your own `args` object with:

```
args = argparse.Namespace(verbose=False, par=1, args=['run', 'test'])
```

In fact you could pass that to the parser:

```
args = parser.parse_args(namespace=args)
```

You could substitute your own 'commandline' list

```
args = parser.parse_args(['--verbose','--par','2'])
```

I often use that format when testing parser code.

By the way, do you really want `par` `nargs=1`?  The default `nargs` takes one argument.  `nargs=1` does the same, but creates a list, `pars=[1]` in the namespace.

With

```
dd = vars(args)
```

you can use all the normal dictionary operations.  For example:

```
dd0 = dict(pars=3, verbose=False)
dd0.update(vars(args))
```

though this doesn't do anything significant if `dd0` contains the same keys as parser.  `args` will have always have those values, whether default or from the commandline.

Another option is to define keyword arguments in your function.

def myaction(verbose=False, pars=1, args=None, **kwargs):
       # do something with these
       print(verbose, pars, args, kwargs)

Use:

```
myaction(**vars(args))
myaction(pars=2, args=[12,34], extra='for kwargs')
myaction(**{'pars':3})
```

Comment: Thanks, there's some really useful stuff here!  I omitted the named-variables in the `main` definition as it was just another-place to have to rewrite them (in addition to the `add_argument`s and in `Sets`).  I do see that the `Sets` object was superfluous.